# Sort PHP Numerically & Identify which is closest to date

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, carousel, usort

I've got an array for events on my site that looks like this:

```
array(
    'title' => 'Name',
    'link' => 'http://www.eventssite.com',
    'image' => '_img/event_img.jpg',
    'location' => 'Florida, US',
    'year' => '2013',
    'date' => 'Dec. 12-14',
    'desc' => 'Description about the event.',
    'dateid' => '1212013'
),
```

I'd like to sort the array before the foreach by the dateid so that they show in the proper Date order.

Additionally I'm trying to identify which one of the events is closest to the actual date, as I am using a carousel type system that needs to know which to display first.

I've researched usort and am not able to get it to go on my own, Thank you for any assistance on these!

Comment: So, just reorder it to be `20131212` and compare. It looks like a trivial task for anyone isn't it?

Comment: `1212013`? Is that Jan 12th, 2013? Dec 1st? 121st day of 2013? Before you get started on sorting, you should fix your date representations to be less ambiguous.

Comment: Where is this array coming from ... im guessing a database? if so why not perform the sort there?

Comment: It's somewhere between 'very difficult' to 'impossible' to order data that doesn't contain the data that you'd like to order it by. Yes, you've got a year, but good luck parsing dates like 'Dec. 12-14' in a sane manner.

Comment: @zerkms I will adjust them to look like a format Date allows

Comment: @MarcB : I have adjusted my arrays to look like the following:
'dateid' => '081414' and 'dateid' => '121714'

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey : They're not in a database, the array is in a separate file which is included on the page which the carousel is used which looks like
'<?php include 'events.php'; foreach ($events as $event) { ?>carousel-div-code-here<?php } ?>'

Comment: @Sammitch : that's what I figured, those were for visual purposes, so I decided creating an additional var dateid would be better suited for sorting

Thank you for the responses thus far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this function: http://php.net/usort

An example would be something like:

```
<?php
//just an array of arrays with the date as one of the values of the array
$array = array(
    array(
        'date' => '05/02/1988',
        'name' => 'Jacob'
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '12/12/1968',
        'name' => 'Sherry'
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '05/15/1978',
        'name' => 'Dave'
    )
);

//usort is used for non conventional sorting. 
//which could help in this case
//NOTICE - we are not setting a variable here! 
//so dont call it like $array = usort(...) you will just be setting $array = true
usort($array,'sortFunction');

//display the results
var_dump($array);

//function called by usort
function sortFunction($a,$b){
    //turn the dates into integers to compare them
    //
    $strA = strtotime($a['date']);
    $strB = strtotime($b['date']);

    //don't worry about sorting if they are equal
    if($strA == $strB){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
            //if a is smaller than b, the move it up by one.
        return $strA < $strB ? -1 : 1; 
    }
}
?>
```

(in case youre interested, line 40 is called a [Ternary](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators))
edited for clarity

Comment: This definitely got me in the right direction!. Posted final code